# WHY from tkinter import * accepts !anchor=SW! BUT import tkinter accepts !anchor="sw"!

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I wonder why when I use from `tkinter import *` the following code works :

```
def draw():
    global visagesPos, visageN, photoV
    can1.create_image(visagesPos[visageN-1][0], visagesPos[visageN-1][1],anchor=SW, image=photoV)

fen1 = Tk()
can1 = Canvas(fen1,bg='dark grey', width=400, height=300)
can1.place(x = 5, y = 5)
draw()
```

But this code is no more accepted when I use `import tkinter`, instead I need to replace the `anchor=SW` with `anchor="sw"`:

```
def draw():
    global visagesPos, visageN, photoV
    can1.create_image(visagesPos[visageN-1][0], visagesPos[visageN-1][1], anchor="sw", image=photoV)

fen1 = tkinter.Tk()
can1 = tkinter.Canvas(fen1,bg='dark grey', width=400, height=300)
can1.place(x = 5, y = 5)
draw()
```

I'm running python3.5.

Comment: I recommend always using the string values. A constant named `SW` that contains the string `"sw"` seems pointless.

Comment: I will do so. Thanks.